# Can I rely on my AV by setting only the "File Exeuction" option?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, nod32, eset

I'm using Eset NOD32 AV program ( version 9 , but it doesn't really matter).

In the "Scan" section I have these  options :

[image]

My personal goal is to

- Still have protection
- Maximize performance ( without hurting protection)

IMO this can be done  , I might be wrong and hence I ask :

**Question**

Can I set only the "File Execution" option so that **only** when file is executing , scanning will occur ?

I mean :

- File open : If I disable this , so file will be read by the "File Execution" phase. so why read it when opening while I can read it when executing ?
- File Creation : If I disable this , fine so a virus can be in that file and if I send that file to a friend , he will be infected , but let's *leave* this for now. I'm talking about my PC **only**. If a virus is in that file , so it will be found when executing.

Considering the above , Is it OK to leave only the "File execution" flag on?

---

NB

It all boils down to the "file Execution" meaning.
clicking on `txt` file , Or an EXE program loading an infected dll ,  is it "executed" ? I don't think so. The loader read its extension and execute the NOTEPAD process. or is txt file actually executed ?

A clarification is needed here.

Additional Info , I don't know if it help but clicking the "info" :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan on `File execution` means that executable files (EXE/DLL typically, but not limited to) will be scanned when executed (mapped to memory as executable sections).

Clicking on a `TXT` file is not considered as execution of that file, because OS will execute associated program (most likely notepad.exe in this case) and this program will then *just* read data from target file.

Thus I'd not recommend to disable scan on `File open` option. Otherwise various scripts and data files may not get scanned at all.

One may be tempting to disable scan on `File creation` as creation of infected file doesn't necessarily pose a security risk. File has to be accessed/executed in order to do some damage.
In fact some AV solutions don't scan created files by default.

I'd be very careful with this. It may be possible to create malicious file that would be then used during boot time when AV is not running yet (for example register a boot driver). This way even simple creation of file without immediate access to it may pose a security risk.

Thus I'd really recommend to leave those settings at defaults. I'd say AV vendor knows its product the best and default settings should fit most of the users.

You wrote that your goal is to `Maximize performance ( without hurting protection)`.

Do you actually have any performance issues with ESET NOD32? If so, I'd recommend to report it on [vendor's forum](https://forum.eset.com/forum/24-eset-nod32-antivirus/). They should help you to identify the problem and hopefully resolve it.